# Overriding values in a column to the next value on list

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, overriding

I'm trying to preprocess a column in Spark dataframe, the column contains int values for example `[41,43,45,59,72]`. I'm trying to process that data to get the next value with a 5 steps for example `41->40, 43->45, 45->45, 59->60 ....`

How can I do it in the most optimal way in a PySpark dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 F.round(F.col('c1') / 5) * 5
```

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([(41,), (43,), (45,), (59,), (72,)], ['c1'])

df = df.withColumn('c2', (F.round(F.col('c1') / 5) * 5).cast('int'))

df.show()
# +---+---+
# | c1| c2|
# +---+---+
# | 41| 40|
# | 43| 45|
# | 45| 45|
# | 59| 60|
# | 72| 70|
# +---+---+
```

*To override*, instead of a new name, use the existing column name:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([(41,), (43,), (45,), (59,), (72,)], ['c1'])

df = df.withColumn('c1', (F.round(F.col('c1') / 5) * 5).cast('int'))

df.show()
# +---+
# | c1|
# +---+
# | 40|
# | 45|
# | 45|
# | 60|
# | 70|
# +---+
```